# ScrollPane стили для Scrollbara

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Как изменить стиль `ScrallBar`?

Такая штука не работает:

```
scroll.getStyleClass().add(".scroll-pane .thumb {-fx-background-color:derive(black,90%);" +
            "-fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0;-fx-background-radius: 0em;}");
```

Пробовал найти какую-то инфу по `Skin`, но кроме Оракловой доки ничего нет.

Так как сделать кастомные элементы в `ScrollBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В возвращаемую коллекцию `getStyleClass()` нужно добавлять не стиль, а имя класса, описанного в `css`. Стили можно писать в `.setStyle( "-fx-..." );`, но для внутренних классов типа `.thumb` или селекторов это не сработает. Так что как-то так:

```
scroll.getStylesheets().add( MainApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/main.css").toExternalForm() );
scroll.getStyleClass().add( "myClass" );
//scroll.setId( "myId" );
```

main.css

```
.myClass .thumb {
    -fx-background-color:derive(black,90%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
}
/*
#myId .thumb {
    -fx-background-color:derive(black,90%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
}
*/
```

Альтернативный вариант без `css` файла( вроде должно сработать, но не проверял ):

```
for ( Node n : scrool.lookupAll( ".trumb" ) ){
    n.setStyle("-fx-background-color:derive(black,90%);" +
        "-fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0;-fx-background-radius: 0em;" );
}
```